# Is this compilation or decompilation side effects?

Tags: java, casting, compilation, decompiler, type-safety

Were running a server . A guy got fired. He deleted source code.
We must decompile....:
I noticed several weird stuff:

1) The variable declerations are also in the middle of the program at random spots
2) No type safety of HashMaps e.g.

```
HashMap<Integer , Boolean> s = new HashMap<Integer , Boolean>();
```

got turned into
    HashMap s = new HashMap();
the same thing happened to Lists and Collections generally. It also has some side effects
that caused some exceptions
    ((Long) list.get(a_long).longValue());
The stuff added were the cast and the longValue call

3)I also noticed some trash coding

Did these things happen because I decompiled the program , or did these things happen due to the compiler or stupidity of ex-developer?

Comment: Lesson: Use a source control system, such as [git](http://git-scm.com/).

Comment: @user3809450 A guy got fired..Bring him back :)

Comment: Some decompilers will handle these things better than others.  Procyon should restore auto-(un)boxing quite well.  It should infer some generics, but there are still known issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are observing is a result of type erasure and autoboxing. In Java generics, the generic types are enforced by the compiler, but the underlying implementation at the byte code level has no notion of the generic types (they are "erased"), which is why these have disappeared. Similarly, conversions between Integer and int or vice-versa (and similarly for other primitives) is done through "autoboxing" which is basically where the compiler is inserting these explicit calls to the conversion methods for you.

Answer (score 3):

> Did these things happen because I decompiled the program , or did
>   these things happen due to the compiler or stupidity of ex-developer?

**This is because of the concept of type-erasure. Generics is a compile time concept and this information is removed during the process of compilation.**

Generics were introduced to the Java language to provide tighter type checks at compile time and to support generic programming.

It Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded. The produced bytecode, therefore, contains only ordinary classes, interfaces, and methods.

Read this for detailed explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html